# Nokia Lumia 525 is not updating to Windows 10

Tags: update, windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-525

My Nokia Lumia 525 is not updating to Windows 10 Mobile. What is the problem and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 4):

Although Microsoft first planned to upgrade all the Windows Phone 8 devices, they recently stated that only some devices will get the upgrade.
Here's the actual list :[image: List of eligible phones for Windows 10 upgrade]

[Source](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-mobile-upgrade?4161f8f5-7e1c-4e98-a5ed-28262407d074=1)

Unfortunately, as you can see, the Lumia 525 is not eligible.